# Is there any way to append data into local excel file using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I have a web page that calculate data about specific thing, this page does not have a database to store data so i want to make an excel file on the server to store data in it when user click 'submit', the problem is that i want to create only one excel file and i want to append new data into this file, can i do that with javascript or jquery ?

EDIT : i prefer making an offline project.

Comment: which language do you use on server side? every server side language has file read-write feauture, just post your data through AJAX, write server side code to create/open_if_already a file to append the data posted

Comment: i have two options; PHP or MVC5

Comment: checkout a very handy website article for your need https://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete

Comment: This looks simple, i will try do this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad, but for the scope of answering,

1) You could use Google Sheets API to store the value to a sheet in the google cloud. (Yes, you can use javascript for this)

2) You could create a node.js server and use javascript to write to csv or an excel file(research for npm modules based on your requirement) and expose it using a REST API for your application

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

Steps: 
1. You can keep one excel sheet on the server, (example- test.csv). 
2. Every time you want to append some data to this excel sheet, you may copy data from test.csv into json format, append the new data into the json (array). 
3. delete the test.csv from server.
4. Use FILE APIs, to create a new csv file by the name test.csv with the data that was generated in json format in step 2.

(This is independent of node/google sheets, can be used with just html, js, and also if your project is in php);

I have a working code for this somewhere in my backup, would try to provide a link here to it.

P.s - This is probably my first answer here, please excuse for any issues.

Comment: Sounds good, i'm waiting for your code and welcome to Stack over flow ! (^_^).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install node.js into your machine to do this locally. (https://nodejs.org/en/download/). It would need a lot of security disables to allow file manipulation on the browser.

After, if your purpose is to only store data, than a CSV file would be easier and lighter (and you can open them with Excel). Run `npm search csv` to check a lot of packages that you can use to work with CSV

If you really need and Excel file, you can install this package `npm install exceljs`. And here is the docs for it https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs